# wso2 ESB pass a complextype to other endpoint

Tags: object, redirect, wso2, esb

I want to orchestrate 2 web services with WSO2 ESB. First endpoint returns a complex type with the name student. How can I pass this student object to another endpoint without any changing.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Following article might help you to achieve your requirement.

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/service-orchestration-with-wso2-esb

You can use the following to store the response in a proerty.

```
<enrich>
            <source type="body" clone="true"/>
            <target type="property" action="child" property="body_of_first_call"/>
         </enrich>
```